# Stripe Apple Pay sandbox Testing account

Tags: android, ios, laravel, stripe-payments, applepay

everyone.

I'd like to ask you that can I test apple pay in India ? Using sandbox account which has been created for US country.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you testing Apple Pay in iOS App or in the web using PaymentRequest Button from Stripe?

Comment: yes and it's completed testing for country India with currency Indian.

Comment: @mukeshkumar were you able to test Apple Pay in India? If yes than how? Because I tried everything still I was not able to see the Apple Pay button

Answer (score 0):

I think yes you can do it . just add a new card from apple pay sandbox .. and go for it

https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/